# CfSetInSyncState does not behave as documented. (CfAPI)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, minifilter

I try to use CfSetInSyncState with an USN.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfsetinsyncstate?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(CFAPI%2FCfSetInSyncState)%3Bk(CfSetInSyncState)%3Bk(DevLang-C%2B%2B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue) says that you can provide an USN and the change will only performed when the USN still matches.

However calling the Method on an NOT_IN_SYNC file with the current USN will not succeed. It returns `0x80070179` "ERROR_CLOUD_FILE_NOT_IN_SYNC". The returned USN value did also not changed.

I have a minimal sample on [github](https://github.com/LokiMidgard/CloudTest) that will demonstrate this.

I have tried different flags to obtain the handle and also using the CreateFile method instead. Opening the file also does not seems to change the USN. But until know I wasn't able to set SyncState if USN was provided nor I could retrieve the current USN from the function.

How can I use `CfSetInSyncState`in a way that it will only set the state to IN_SYNC when the USN did not change.

---

## Edit

I updated the sample, so it will cleanup potential previous files and generate some Output:

```
Cloud sample test!
Try Set In Sync

Created placeholder test1.txt with USN 1631131882568.
Try to set Sync state IN_SYNC
Faild to set InSyncState
USN was NOT changed.


Try Set NOT In Sync

Created placeholder test2.txt with USN 1631131882728.
setting USN variable to -1 But will still work for NOT_IN_SYNC.
Seting Sync state to NOT IN SYNC.
USN was changed now 0.
```

I run this in the AppPackage project, since this seems to be a requirement of the CfAPI.

I would expect that the first block (setting non sync file to sync) would not fail, since the USN did not changed before the `cfSetInSyncState` call. *(This is what currently blocks me)*

I would also expect to get the current USN when the method returns, even if it failed. But I'm not so sure about that one. The documentation says `...value after setting the in-sync state...` which I can interpret only if successful.

In the second block (sync file to non synced) I would expect to actually receive the current USN instead of 0.

Currently I try different approaches in opening the file handle, but nothing so far helped. Is there an error in registering the SyncRoot, that some flag must be set for it to work?

Comment: When creating a new file/file-placeholder, the `CfSetInSyncState` set `CF_IN_SYNC_STATE_NOT_IN_SYNC` success with setting `tmpUsn` to zero. If the file is exiting, `CfCreatePlaceholders` will fails with `0x800700b7`(Cannot create a file when the file already exists.) In this test I stop onedrive to sync, otherwise, if onedrive is in syncing state, `CfCreatePlaceholders` will fails with `0x8007018b`(Access to the cloud file is denied.). So I can't reproduce your issue. You can try my tests or show some steps for how to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Thanks for the fast response. I updated the code on github. I have two seperate files now one for sync->NOT_sync and one NOT_sync->sync. My problem is primarly with NOT_sync->sync. If you run the updated sample I would expect that you get the same output. (beside the numeric values)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why this question was voted offtopic. I think it was to vague maybe. I tried to concrete my problem, so it will no longer be regarded off-topic. If this was not the problem, a hint would be nice ;) The problem I have `I call a Method that does not what I wan/expectt` seems to be a programming related problem.

Answer (score 0):

- For newly create placeholder with [`CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_FLAG_NONE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/ne-cfapi-cf_placeholder_create_flags):
  To make it change in-sync state successfully by `CfSetInSyncState`, you can set the input USN to `0` instead of the USN returned from `CfCreatePlaceholders`.
- For newly create placeholder with [`CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_FLAG_MARK_IN_SYNC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/ne-cfapi-cf_placeholder_create_flags): Either `0` or the USN returned from `CfCreatePlaceholders` as input will change in-sync state successfully by `CfSetInSyncState`.

> I would expect that the first block (setting non sync file to sync)
>   would not fail

Edited code line: `tmpUsn = 0;// usn;`

Result snapshot:

[image]

**Update:**
**`CfSetInSyncState` seems not return actual USN. You can get actual USN via `DeviceIoControl` with `FSCTL_READ_FILE_USN_DATA` like this:**

```
#define BUF_LEN 1024
// ...

CHAR Buffer[BUF_LEN];
DWORD dwBytes;
HANDLE hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
USN_RECORD_V2* fUsn = NULL;

hFile = CreateFile(TEXT("C:\\Test\\Cloud\\test1.txt"),
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    0,
    NULL);

if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("CreateFile failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    return;
}

memset(Buffer, 0, BUF_LEN);

if (!DeviceIoControl(hFile,
    FSCTL_READ_FILE_USN_DATA,
    NULL,
    0,
    Buffer,
    BUF_LEN,
    &dwBytes,
    NULL))
{
    printf("Read journal failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    return;
}

printf("****************************************\n");

fUsn = (USN_RECORD_V2*)Buffer;

printf("USN: %I64x\n", fUsn->Usn);
printf("File name: %.*S\n",
    fUsn->FileNameLength / 2,
    fUsn->FileName);
printf("Reason: %x\n", fUsn->Reason);

CloseHandle(hFile);
```

Refer to [Fsutil usn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-usn), [`FSCTL_READ_FILE_USN_DATA IOCTL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-fsctl_read_file_usn_data).

Comment: I am aware that using an USN value of 0 will always set the sync state. But I need to check if there are not new changes. **Usecase**: 1. Some file got changed so it is not in sync. 2. Perform changes in cloud. 3. Set In Sync. **The problem**: between 2 and 3, new changes may accour. If I use 0 as USN the files would marked as in sync but there would be mssing changes. **ideally**: 1. Some file got changed so it is not in sync. 2. Get the USN of file 3. Perform changes in cloud. 4. Set In Sync with USN from 2. This gurates that if 4 is successfull there are no missing changes in the cloud.

Comment: Also if I use Zero as USN it will set the SyncState, But the docu also says that "on return the value [USN] is the final USN after the operation. When you check the file with  `fsutil usn readdata <FILE_NAME>` the USN will most likely not be zero (which is till the value after the return). I must somehow use this method worong.

Comment: @lokimidgard I can reproduce this issue and `CfSetInSyncState` seems not return actual USN. You can get actual USN via `DeviceIoControl` with `FSCTL_READ_FILE_USN_DATA` as a workaround. You can refer to my update answer for an example code of how to use this API. For document issue I'll consult related engineer  and update to you if there is any progress.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround to get the USN. By the way, your sample seems to miss the length of the buffer `const size_t BUF_LEN = 80;` I assume for the USN as input there is no such an easy workaround.

Comment: @lokimidgard I add BUF_LEN definition. Hope this answer helps.

Comment: I also tried to use `CfUpdatePlaceholder` as a workaround for USN input, but this also has the same issues as `CfSetInSyncState`. I havn't found any other Methods that use USN in CFApi yet.

Comment: Any luck in finding out how to use USN as an input for `CfSetInSyncState`? It is an essential function to find out if all changes are processed. It is currently blocking me and could fail our Project :(

Comment: @lokimidgard I've consulted the related engineer for helping on this issue and update to you if there is any progress.

Comment: I know you tell me if there is progress, but have you an estimation? It would be helpful for planing. currently I work around this issue on other stuff. However, I'm running out on other topics. So I may be forced to put this project on ice until resolved. Even a rough estimation like "not in the next 4 month" would be helpful.

Comment: @lokimidgard I am keeping follow up this issue and I've consult the related engineer to see if there is an update.

Comment: @lokimidgard Where are you able to find a solution for this issue?

Comment: unfortunatly no. But I no longer work on this project. I cant even say if the project is still developed.

Comment: @RitaHan Any updates regarding this issue, it is weird, that the API is not behaving like described.